# Jekyll static page not rendering markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm a complete Jekyll newbie, so I apologize if the answer to this is self-evident, but a static page that I created in markdown on my github.io is not rendering things like headings and even new lines. I'm not sure what liquid syntax or what else is needed in the file in question (CL262.md in that directory of my repo). Thanks for the help!

https://dlibatique.github.io/CL262/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it may be as simple as adding spaces after your #'s for your markdown heading definitions eg.

```
###Texts
```

Should be:

```
### Texts
```

For the rendering engine to pick it up

Comment: That's embarrassingly easy. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, didn't know that was a thing! Just did so. Thanks!